# DataTables pagination prevents $_POST from getting all checkbox values

Tags: php, jquery, checkbox, datatables

I have a table that has a checkbox on it. I'm trying to POST all the checked checkboxes but whenever I submit my button the only values it gets are from the current page of checked row.

#### form

```
<form method="post" action="post_chk.php">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx[]" value="$key[data]">
    </td>
</form>
```

#### post_chk.php

```
<?php
   $data = $_POST['chkbx'];
   var_dump($data); exit;
?>
```

how can I get all data from the datatables pagination..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following codes are used to check all the input in dataTables.

```
var table = $('#dataTable').DataTable();

$('#checkall').click(function () {
    $(':checkbox', table.rows().nodes()).prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

If the problem continous then dont't use pagination, use `scroll-y` instead of it.

```
$(".dataTable").dataTable({
paging:false,
scrollY:400
});
```

Comment: The OP is asking how to have specific checkboxes from non visible paginations show up on the backend when submitting the post. This just 'checks all' which was not the question.